# Pointers malfunctioning in the implementation of double ended queues

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, queue, deque

I learnt the below implemented logic from a book but it seems as though my front pointer isn't where it should be once I start to add elements from rear and front. The order of elements does not become as expected.

Suggestions on how I might fix my logic in the add_first and add_last method?

```
class Deque():
    DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10

def __init__(self):
    self._data = [None]*Deque.DEFAULT_CAPACITY
    self._size = 0
    self._front = 0
    
def __len__(self):
    return self._size

def is_empty(self):
    return self._size == 0

def first(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception('Queue is empty')
    return self._data[self._front]

def last(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception('Queue is empty')
    back = (self._front + self._size - 1) % len(self._data)
    return self._data[back]

def delete_first(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception('Queue is empty')
    answer = self._data[self._front]
    self._data[self._front] = None
    self._front = (self._front + 1) % len(self._data)
    self._size -= 1
    return answer

def delete_last(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception('Queue is empty')
    back = (self._front + self._size - 1) % len(self._data)
    answer = self._data[back]
    self._data[back] = None
    self._size -= 1
    return answer
    
def add_first(self, e):
    if self._size == len(self._data):
        self._resize(2*len(self.data))
    self._front = (self._front - 1) % len(self._data)
    self._data[self._front] = e
    self._size += 1
    
def add_last(self, e):
    if self._size == len(self._data):
        self._resize(2*len(self.data))
    avail = (self._front + self._size) % len(self._data)
    self._data[avail] = e
    self._size += 1
    
def _resize(self, cap):
    old = self._data
    self._data = [None]*cap
    walk = self._front
    for k in range(self._size):
        self._data[k] = old[walk]
        walk = (1 + walk) % len(old)
    self._front = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your class method add_first  is that if front pointer points 0 it changes to the last element.
I changed as minimum as I could and added comments hope it helps.

```
 def add_first(self, e):
        if self._size == len(self._data) or self._front==0: #if front is atfirst element we need resize
            self._resize(2 * len(self._data))
        self._front = (self._front - 1) % len(self._data)
        self._data[self._front] = e
        self._size += 1



    def add_last(self, e):
        if self._front+self._size == len(self._data):#As there might be Nones at the beginning
            self._resize(2 * len(self._data))
        avail = (self._front + self._size) % len(self._data)
        self._data[avail] = e
        self._size += 1


    def _resize(self, cap):
        ##adding cap//4 Nones at the beginning and cap//4 Nones at the end. This shifts front by cap//4
        self._front = cap//4+self._front
        old = self._data
        self._data = [None] * (cap//4)+old+[None] * (cap//4)
```

Comment: After resizing on different conditions, does the property of a circular array still hold i.e, it grows dynamically but only after utilizing the None memory locations currently present in the array?

Comment: No this code doesn't use all the None and then trigger resize but it triggers when the leftmost None or rightmost None has been hit. We could code two different resize function to reduce adding unnecessary  None.